# Phrase for the cognitive bias that I can best describe as "abundance bias"

Tags: phrase-requests

My sentence is:

> Hence this option is free of abundance bias

Say, if a doctor sees 100 patients with X and someone who has Y (which has symptoms similar to X) comes in. The doctor fails to consider any subtleties that might make it different from X and just diagnoses X. This doctor has "abundance bias" because the X was more common. You could say it's actually confirmation bias but that'll be when the doctor diagnoses based on his subjective experience rather than X being more widespread.

I want to replace the term "**abundance bias**" with the properly defined term rooted in psychology/cognitive sciences that denotes that the option will account for all subtleties and won't be biased towards stuff that happens to be more common.

Comment: What exactly is "abundance bias"? Do you perhaps mean "*abundant* bias," which would instead utilize an adjective modifying a noun rather than a noun modifying a noun? Unless, of course, it is known as abundance bias...

Comment: It's just something I made up because I couldn't think of the right term. Basically, I want the term for that cognitive bias that arises when a particular thing is perceived to be much more common than the rest and hence it seems the only case and the rest is disregarded/not considered.

Comment: More common than the rest of what?

Comment: Anything. Say, if a doctor sees 100 patients with X and someone who has Y (which has symptoms similar to X) comes in. The doctor fails to consider any subtleties that might make it different from X and just diagnoses X. This doctor has "abundance bias" because the X was more common. You could say it's actually confirmation bias but that'll be when the doctor diagnoses based on his subjective experience rather than X being more widespread.

Comment: I see now. It's a good question.

Comment: @HMK -- feel free to edit your question to include the additional information you put in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware, "abundance bias" is already in use and has a different implication.

It could be **salience bias** if the concept fits the broader context.

[Salience Bias](https://thedecisionlab.com/bias/salience-bias/) (The Decision Lab)

> The salience bias (also known as perceptual salience) refers to the fact that individuals are more likely to focus on items or information that are more prominent and ignore those that are less so. This creates a bias in favour of things that are striking and perceptible …

Comment: Yes, this sounds most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It's called the *Baader-Meinhof phenomenon* (or *effect*) or the *frequency illusion.*

https://science.howstuffworks.com/life/inside-the-mind/human-brain/baader-meinhof-phenomenon.htm

Comment: Baader Meinhof implies that the commonness of X arose only after you noticed X. I'm looking for a term that'd assume X being accepted as common by everyone. Like it's omnipresent or something

Answer (score 0):

Reading up on cognitive biases on Wikipedia, I found [representativeness heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representativeness_heuristic) which seems the closest term to what I was trying to describe, although it is not a cognitive bias. So I have modified my sentence to -

> Hence this option is free of **any subjective representativeness heuristic**

EDIT - After reading the answer by Kris, I have modified my sentence as that is more what I'd been looking for

> Hence this option is free of **salience bias**